# пояснить рекурсивную функцию

Tags: python, рекурсия

```
def min_list(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    return L[0] if L[0] < min_list(L[1:]) else min_list(L[1:])
```

я понимаю что написано, вернуть первое значение списка, если оно является наименьшим. Если же нет, вернуть весь список со второго элемента –

Comment: но нужно пояснение что происходит под капотом...

Comment: Под капотом происходит обращение к функции `min_list` с разными аргументами (какими - вы уже и сами поняли). Вам просто нужно по шагам расписать все эти обращения к функции. Она обращается сама к себе, но всё время меняет аргумент. Нужно просто всё расписать на бумажке и станет понятно.

Comment: `Если же нет, вернуть весь список со второго элемента ` - это неверно. Должно быть "если же нет, вернуть минимальный элемент для подсписка начиная со второго элемента"

Answer (score 4):

Под капотом происходит обращение к функции `min_list` с разными аргументами (какими - вы уже и сами поняли). Вам просто нужно по шагам расписать все эти обращения к функции. Она обращается сама к себе, но всё время меняет аргумент. Нужно просто всё расписать на бумажке и станет понятно.

Посмотрим простейший случай - обращение к функции с `L = [1,2,3]`:

```
def min_list([1,2,3]):
    if len([1,2,3]) == 1: # не сработало
        return 1
    return 1 if 1 < min_list([1,2,3][1:]) else min_list([1,2,3][1:])
```

Этот проход порождает ещё вызовы функции - один с аргументом `[2,3]` и второй с хм, таким же аргументом (если будет выполнена ветка `else`). Функция написана не оптимально, не хорошо вызывать два раза с одним аргументом, ну да ладно:

```
# L = [1,2,3][1:]
def min_list([2,3]):
    if len([2,3]) == 1: # не сработало
        return 2
    return 2 if 2 < min_list([2,3][1:]) else min_list([2,3][1:])
```

И снова надо вычислить функцию, чтобы отработал `if`:

```
# L = [2,3][1:]
def min_list([3]):
    if len([3]) == 1: # сработало!
        return 3
    # дальше код на этом проходе уже не работает, поскольку сработал return
```

Так, отработал `return`, возвращаемся на предыдущий шаг, подставив результат работы функции:

```
#   return 2 if 2 < min_list([2,3][1:]) else min_list([2,3][1:])
    return 2 if 2 < 3 else 3
```

Отсюда вернётся `2`, идём ещё выше по рекурсии:

```
#    return 1 if 1 < min_list([1,2,3][1:]) else min_list([1,2,3][1:])
     return 1 if 1 < 2 else 2
```

Возвращается `1`. Всё, больше вложенностей не было, это окончательный результат.

Comment: спасибо большое! вроде поняла:
сначала как бы расписываются все случаи вплоть до терминального, а затем снизу вверх идет вычисление мин. элемента. Правильно?

Comment: @Elena Ну, почти. Так то надо прямо смотреть с карандашом куда пошло управление, если пошёл опять вызов функции - идти в эту функцию с новыми аргументами и т.д. В данном случае ветка `else` ни разу не сработала, а могла сработать, но её сразу считать не надо было, а только по мере срабатывания. В общем, это с карандашом ходить и смотреть.